# Reading an input stream without extracting

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to count the number of characters in an input stream up to the first non-digit without actually extracting characters from the stream.  The input can contain any number of characters.  I need to do this to determine if I should grow a dynamic array before storing the digits in the stream in the array.

I am limited to the following libraries: iostream, cstring, cctype

I was thinking something like:

```
int counter = 0;
const char * s = cin.getline();

while( s[counter] <= '0' || s[counter] >= '9' )
{
   counter++;
}
```

But I'm having some trouble getting that to work.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd just grow the dynamic array as needed! Copying characters is extremely fast and if the array is grown exponentially the overall complexity is still linear.

Comment: That makes sense.  I don't know why I wasn't just doing that.  For some reason I had it in my head that I'd have to resize prior to extraction.  I just added a simple: if( maxSize == counter ){ Grow(); } and it works fine now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
std::istream::pos_type start = is.tellg();

while (std::isdigit((is >> std::ws).peek()) && is.ignore())
    ;

counter = in.tellg();
is.seekg(start, std::ios_base::beg);
```

Does whitespace count as a non-digit character in this case? If so, remove the second line from the `while()` loop which discards leading whitespace.

Comment: If you want to seek, you probably want to seek back to the start of the sequence. Seeking forward for each character will be hideously wxpensive, too! You'd much better use `sbumpc()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Not understanding what "seeking back to the start" means? Can you explain? But I will take your other suggestion! :)

Comment: the request was to determine how many characters will be coming and not consume them. Your code does consume them! You'll need something like `std::istream::pos_type start(in.seekg(0, std::ios_base::cur)); ... ; in.seekg(start);`

Comment: @DietmarKühl Okay I see what you're saying. :D